# How to change CSS in Controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I m trying to do a workaround for a bug. i need to just change the css of an element when an other checkbox is clicked. But it is not working.. It just works when i click on an other button somewhere else but when i click on the checkbox the view is not being refreshed maybe ? 
Any ideas ?

View:

```
<input
    type="checkbox"  
    value="application.callback" id="telefonBox"
    ng-click="application.callback = !application.callback; toggleClass(application.callback)"
/>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.toggleClass = function(newValue) {
    var element = angular.element(document.querySelector('#additional'));

    if (newValue) {
        element.toggleClass("tooltip-agent tooltip-agentChecked ");
    } else {
        element.toggleClass("tooltip-agentChecked tooltip-agent");
    }
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

i tried this to but not working

```
$scope.$watch('$scope.application.callback', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    var element = angular.element(document.querySelector('#additional'));
    if (newValue) {
        element.toggleClass("tooltip-agent tooltip-agentChecked ");
    } else {
        element.toggleClass("tooltip-agentChecked tooltip-agent ");
    }
```

Comment: add more code, esp the additional part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `ng-modal` into checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="application.callback">
```

and `ng-class` into your `#additional` element

```
<div id="additional" ng-class="{true:'tooltip-agent tooltip-agentChecked', false:'tooltip-agentChecked tooltip-agent'}[application.callback]"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/mavoyo/1/edit?html,css,output)

You should not manipulate elements in angular as much as possible, you can do it easier with `ng-class` like this

```
<div id="test" ng-class='{ active: vm.isChecked }'>
  lorem
</div>
```

`ng-class` accepts an object as parameter, in this case it's `{ active: vm.isChecked }` which mean if `vm.isChecked` evaluates to true, the `active` class will be applied to the element

Answer (score 0):

```
  $scope.selection = function($event) {
  var checkbox = $event.target;
  var action = (checkbox.checked ? 'check' : 'uncheck');
    if(action == "check")
       angular.element(document.querySelector('#additional')).addClass("tooltip-agent tooltip-agentChecked");
    else
       angular.element(document.querySelector('#additional')).addClass("tooltip-agentChecked tooltip-agen");
};
  });


  <input type="checkbox" id="additional" ng-model="check" ng-click="selection($event)"  >
```